# In ZF2 how to Escape HTML in Custom View Helpers

Tags: view, zend-framework2, escaping, view-helpers, zend-view

[Here](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/07/20/zend-framework-2-create-your-custom-view-helper/), I see someone suggesting to extend the `Zend\View\Helper\Escaper\AbstractHelper;`, resulting in something like this:

```
namespace Photo\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\Escaper\AbstractHelper;

class Imghelper extends AbstractHelper
{
protected $_baseUrl = null;
protected $_exists = array();

public function __construct ()
{
    $url = PUBLIC_PATH;
    $root = '/' . trim($url, '/');

    if ($root == "/")
      {$root = "";}

    $this->_baseUrl = $root . "/";
}

public function escape($value)
{
   return $this->getEscaper()->escapeHtml($value);
}

public function __invoke($path, $params = array())
{
           $plist = array();
    $str = null;

    $imgpath = $this->_baseUrl . ltrim($path);

    if (!isset($this->_exists[$path]))
      {$this->_exists[$path] = file_exists(realpath($imgpath));}

    if (!isset($params['alt']))
      {$params['alt'] = '';}

    foreach ($params as $param => $value)
      {$plist[] = $param . '="' . $this->escape($value) . '"';}

            $str = " ".join(" ", $plist);
    $p = ($this->_exists[$path]) ? $this->_baseUrl.ltrim($path,'/') : null;

    if (isset($p))
      {return '<img src="'.$p.'" '.$str.' />';}
}


}
```

However, when I try it in my codes, I get an Error

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of Application\View\Helper\Imghelper::__invoke() should be compatible with Zend\View\Helper\Escaper\AbstractHelper::__invoke($value, $recurse = 0) in ...
```

Is it ok to error the error message? Or is there any better ways to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend extending the Abstract Escape helper since you aren't writing an escape helper. Stick to your original plan and just extend `Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper`. You can then access the escape helpers via. `$this->view->escapeHtml()`, `$this->view->escapeJs()` and so on.